# I am not able to use sheety.co on google sheets to extract data on pycharm

Tags: python, google-sheets

I am not able to get the output of the google sheet as a printed statement

```
import requests
import csv
from datetime import datetime

# Sheety API endpoint (replace with your actual Sheety endpoint)
sheety_endpoint = "https://api.sheety.co/50da43782c34743f62f98c4fef079287/patientsOnChemotherapyPythonProject/trialOneOfDoingThat"

# Function to fetch patient data from Sheety and return as a list of dictionaries
def fetch_patient_data(sheety_endpoint):
    response = requests.get(sheety_endpoint)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()

        # Extract the relevant data from Sheety response (including 'name', 'start_date', 'protocol', 'antibiotics' columns)
        patient_info = [{'name': entry['name'],
                         'start_date': entry['start_date'],
                         'protocol': entry.get('protocol', 'N/A'),  # Handle missing protocol
                         'antibiotics': entry.get('antibiotics', 'No')}  # Handle missing antibiotics
                       for entry in data['sheetName']]

        return patient_info
    else:
        print("Error fetching data from Sheety API.")
        return []

# Function to calculate and display the day of chemotherapy for a patient
def calculate_chemo_day(patient):
    name = patient['name']
    start_date_input = patient['start_date']

    try:
        # Parse the start date string into a datetime object
        start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date_input, "%Y-%m-%d")

        # Calculate the current date
        current_date = datetime.now()

        # Calculate the number of days since the start of chemotherapy
        days_since_start = (current_date - start_date).days

        # Update the day of chemotherapy for the patient
        day_of_chemo = days_since_start + 1  # Add 1 to start counting from 1

        # Print the patient's information
        print(f"{name} is on day {day_of_chemo} of chemotherapy, protocol: {patient['protocol']}, antibiotics: {patient['antibiotics']}")
    except ValueError:
        print(f"Invalid date format for {name}. Please use YYYY-MM-DD format.")

# Fetch patient data from Sheety
patient_data = fetch_patient_data(sheety_endpoint)

# Loop through the list of patients and calculate/display the day of chemotherapy
for patient in patient_data:
    calculate_chemo_day(patient)
```

Please see the image for the google sheet that I have tried
I have hidden patient and physician information

[The sheet I am attempting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkNnw.png)

I am expecting this result:

```
XXXX is on day 4 of chemotherapy with protocol  and is not on antibiotics

XXXX is on day 13 of chemotherapy with protocol FlAG- IDA and is not on antibiotics

XXXXis on day 15 of chemotherapy with protocol Vidaza/venetoclax and is on antibiotics on day 2023-09-19: tazocin

XXX is on day 23 of chemotherapy with protocol 2+5 and midostaurin and is on antibiotics on day 2023-10-02: ertapenem
```

Comment: I am sorry but I am confused about exactly what is your problem. Question title=`I am not able to use sheety.co on google sheets to extract data on pycharm` but the question references a spreadsheet and says `I am not able to get the output of the google sheet as a printed statement`.  Would you please clarify: is your problem getting data from sheety.co into your spreadsheet (and have you raised this with sheety.co support?), or is it querying data in your spreadsheet to produce your expected results?

Comment: First of all thank you for giving me the time to answer my question. Second thing,  i am using the code and trying to get an output but it giving me either an error [sheetName] keyerror, or it is giving me process executed with exit code 0 but not print statement, like the one am expecting . Thank you so much for your help .

Answer (score 0):

````
#sorry i found out the answer later on

import requests
from datetime import datetime

# Sheety API endpoint
url = "https://api.sheety.co/*****"


def fetch_patients_data(url):
    """Fetch patients data from Sheety API."""
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise ValueError(f"Failed to fetch data from API. Status code: {response.status_code}")
    return response.json()['fullListPatients']


def calculate_chemo_day(start_date_str):
    """Calculate the current day of chemotherapy."""
    try:
        start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date_str, "%Y-%m-%d")
        current_date = datetime.now()
        days_since_start = (current_date - start_date).days
        return days_since_start + 1
    except ValueError:
        return None


def main():
    patients = fetch_patients_data(url)
    for patient in patients:
        name = patient.get('name', 'Unknown Patient')
        start_date = patient.get('start_date', None)
        disease = patient.get('disease', 'Unknown Disease')
        protocol_name = patient.get('protocol_name', 'Unknown Protocol')
        mrp = patient.get('mrp', 'Unknown MRP')

        if start_date:
            chemo_day = calculate_chemo_day(start_date)
            if chemo_day:
                print(
                    f"{name} (Disease: {disease}, Protocol: {protocol_name}, MRP: {mrp}) is on day {chemo_day} of chemotherapy.")
            else:
                print(f"{name} (Disease: {disease}, Protocol: {protocol_name}, MRP: {mrp}) has an invalid start date.")
        else:
            print(
                f"{name} (Disease: {disease}, Protocol: {protocol_name}, MRP: {mrp}) has not started chemotherapy yet.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

#this created the output that i needed```
````